# Submit form issue. Posted data is a collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

My form keys are:

```
Request.Form.AllKeys
{string[9]}
    [0]: "__RequestVerificationToken"
    [1]: "stud.LastName[0]"
    [2]: "stud.FirstName[0]"
    [3]: "stud.Number[0]"
    [4]: "stud.LastName[1]"
    [5]: "stud.FirstName[1]"
    [6]: "stud.Number[1]"
```

They all have values.
My action  looks like this:

```
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Student[] stud)
```

Student class has properties :FirstName, LastName, Number.

The problem is that stud is null?
Isn't a way to get it populated with submitted data, o or have to take the data from Request.Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have this kind of values *(note the changed [] location)*

```
Request.Form.AllKeys
{string[9]}
    [0]: "__RequestVerificationToken"
    [1]: "stud[0].LastName"
    [2]: "stud[0].FirstName"
    [3]: "stud[0].Number"
    [4]: "stud[1].LastName"
    [5]: "stud[1].FirstName"
    [6]: "stud[1].Number"
```

Something wrong is going on in your views - generated inputs(and when submitted, form values) do not have '[]' in right places in thier names. Take a look at [this article by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about model binding to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(List<Student> students)
```

Comment: This might help http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx